# GitLab-Ci extract coverage value into variable for threshold comparison

Tags: gitlab, code-coverage, gitlab-ci

I have a `coverage` task in `GitLab` set to certain threshold, meaning every build that does not met the threshold criteria should be set to failed.

Here is output from my `coverage` run

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18:00 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-21T15:23:37+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 65M/876M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
coverage line-rate="43.76%"
```

The `coverage` task in `.gitlab-ci.yml` is configured as is

```
coverage:
  coverage: '/coverage line-rate="(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)"/'
  variables:
    min_coverage: 50
    coverage_result: ${coverage}
    coverage_test: '/coverage line-rate="(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)"'
  stage: test
  script:
  - make coverage
  - echo coverage
  - echo "${coverage}"
  - echo "${coverage_result}"
  - echo "${min_coverage}"
  - echo "${coverage_test}"
  - if [ "${min_coverage}" -gt "${coverage}" ]; then exit 1 fi
```

I have not been able to extract the `43.76` value for the `if` comparison